# Algolia reindex command fails with exception in urllib3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, search, algolia

I'm trying to use algolia with my django project. However, i've been running into this strange exception that I have not seen before. When I run the command,

python3 manage.py algolia_reindex

I get the following

```
    The following models were reindexed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util.py", line 144, in _validate_timeout
    float(value)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/algoliasearch/management/commands/algolia_reindex.py", line 22, in handle
    batch_size=options.get('batchsize', None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/algoliasearch/models.py", line 207, in reindex_all
    self.__tmp_index.clear_index()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/algoliasearch/index.py", line 560, in clear_index
    return self._perform_request(self.write_hosts, '/clear', 'POST')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/algoliasearch/index.py", line 792, in _perform_request
    params=params, body=body, is_search=is_search)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/algoliasearch/client.py", line 499, in _perform_request
    params=params, data=body, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 316, in send
    timeout = TimeoutSauce(connect=timeout, read=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util.py", line 116, in __init__
    self._connect = self._validate_timeout(connect, 'connect')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util.py", line 147, in _validate_timeout
    "int or float." % (name, value))
ValueError: Timeout value connect was (1, 30), but it must be an int or float.
```

Can anyone help me resolve this problem. It doesn't seem to be from any of my files. So, I think this is just a config problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error happens because of an incompatibility between your **urllib3** and **requests** version. You can solve the problem by updating **urllib3** and **requests**:

```
pip install --upgrade urllib3 requests
```

Another workaround is to define a custom value for the timeout, in your application's [AppConfig](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#configuring-applications).

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib import algoliasearch

class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'your_app'

    def ready(self):
        algoliasearch.algolia_engine.client.timeout = 30
        algoliasearch.algolia_engine.client.search_timeout = 5

        YourModel = self.get_model('your_model')
        algoliasearch.register(YourModel)
```

Comment: I've run into what looks like the same issue...when we upgraded urllib3 from 1.5-7 to 1.10.4 we found that cloud-init got errors at startup (cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects).   Can you say more about the urllib3/requests incompatibility?  Which versions work and which don't?

Comment: Our requirements are requests>=2.4.0. It seems that requests embeded a version of urllib3 (currently 1.10.4), https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tree/master/requests/packages

Comment: Unfortunately for us the more modern versions of requests requires python 2.7 and we're stuck at 2.6.   So, our only option (other than upgrading everything) is to downgrade urlilib.  Unfortunately in the rats-nest of competing requirements that seems to preclude us from use ElasticSearch Curator which requires the newer urllib3.   Java...all is forgiven!